# A question about policy gradient with function approximation

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, policy-gradient

I've just read a paper about policy gradient: *Sutton, R. S., McAllester, D. A., Singh, S. P., & Mansour, Y. (2000). Policy gradient methods for reinforcement learning with function approximation. In Advances in neural information processing systems (pp. 1057-1063)*.

The theorem 2 in that paper confuses me a lot:

[image]

I agree that this theorem is reasonable. And a possible choice of $f_w$ is also given in that paper.

However, in fact, we usually use an appropriate neural network to estimate the $Q$ function, i.e., the $f_w$ is usually represented by a neural network. It seems that the neural network does not meet the conditions given in theorem 2. So what happens here? Is neural network so powerful that we don't need to consider this theorem, or does this theorem can still be satisfied?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://homes.cs.washington.edu/~todorov/courses/amath579/reading/PolicyGradient.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Eq. 4 is a sufficient but not essential condition. Below is a brief proof.

[image: Proof of sufficient but not essential]

Thus, we may find other functions to satisfy the compatible condition. Yes, NN usually is not one of them. Some research is being done to find a solution for your question 2.